# Startup security utility menu not properly popping up

Tags: recovery

I am trying to configure the security utility but I get this menu instead: [image]
What I am doing is attempting to install windows on an external drive. I am following the steps from [this video](https://youtu.be/3IhW722IMwE).

Comment: It's hard to tell because the words in the message are not readable.  Pictures of errors are not preferred on this site.  You can [edit] your question to include what, exactly, you were trying to do, what the error message says, and what you've done to fix this yourself.

Comment: Clicking on the image brings up a larger window. This is the text which is shown: "Firmware password protection is off. Turn on a firmware password to prevent this computer from starting up from a different hard disk, CD, or DVD without the password." Button (greyed out) reads "Turn On Firmware Password..."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I updated my question.

Comment: If you're asking about the T2 chip security settings, you won't have those unless you have a T2 chip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This utility can only be run on the following Macs with the T2 Security Chip:

- iMac Pro
- Mac Pro introduced in 2019
- Mac mini introduced in 2018
- MacBook Air introduced in 2018 or later
- MacBook Pro introduced in 2018 or later

More information about the Startup Security Utility can be found at this [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198).

Information about the T2 chip can be found at this [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198).

Comment: Darn! Too bad my Mac doesn't support the function, but thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

That step of changing the security utility settings is only for Macs with a T2 chip (newer macs). You don't have one because it did not give you the option. Just skip that part and continue to follow the tutorial. When prompted to select the startup drive, select the blue win folder icon and it will load.

This resolved the issue for me and for a user who commented on the video you linked.

Answer (score 0):

a tip that might help is apple requires Macs to be shutdown and wait 5 seconds before going into macOS recovery. (this is the correct procedure)

If you restart your Mac and then go straight into recovery that is actually (fallback macOS Recovery) so terminal and startup security will not work it's only meant to reinstall the OS and fix disk issues.

The correct method to resolve this issue from apple themselves is:

**MacOS Recovery requires:**

- The silicon Mac to be shutdown first
- wait 5 seconds after the screen goes black
- Then press and hold the power button, don't let go until you see "loading startup options"
- Then everything will work
- Same process goes for T2 chip Macs

(*if they still don't and your sure you followed all instructions a slight possibly the firmware needs to be revived: but at a* **last restort**)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/mac 
(note apple is aware this page is outdated for the macOS recovery section, it should be updated soon: missing the 5 second part)